# Falcon closing the connection too early

Tags: python, gunicorn, falconframework

Falcon framework never returns the entire response. All I get from `curl` (or any other HTTP tool) is this:

```
$ curl -q -D - -o - "localhost:8000/post_account?email=someone@example.com

HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Server: gunicorn/19.4.5
Date: Thu, 31 Mar 2016 11:36:49 GMT
Connection: close
content-length: 3
content-type: application/json; charset=utf-8

curl: (18) transfer closed with 3 bytes remaining to read
```

### index.py

This is the bootstrapping script that defines the routes.

```
import falcon
from routes import route_account


app = falcon.API()
post_account = route_account.RoutePostAccount()

# Routes
app.add_route('/post_account', post_account)
```

### route_account.py

This is the route handler class. I checked and the result received from `_result = account.create_account(**_payload)` is good.

```
from falcon.util import uri
from objects.account_base import AccountBase

account = AccountBase()


class RoutePostAccount(object):

    @staticmethod
    def on_get(req, resp):

        # Convert query parameters string to dict
        _payload = uri.parse_query_string(req.query_string)
        # Create account
        _result = account.create_account(**_payload)
        # Send response
        resp.status = _result.get('status', {}).get('code')
        resp.body = _result
```

### Webserver

```
$ gunicorn index:app
```

Does someone see what I don't see? Thanks for any help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `gunicorn index:app --log-level DEBUG` to start your gunicorn workers. Then, try your curl command again and look at the gunicorn console: there must be an error. I think `account.create_account(**_payload)` is returning something invalid. Example: if you're running it on python 3 then it must be returning a dictionary but falcon expects a byte string so it fails and closes the connection. You must serialize (to json, xml, whatever you like) the output of `account.create_account(**_payload)`. This way:

**route_account.py**:

```
import json

from falcon.util import uri
from objects.account_base import AccountBase

account = AccountBase()


class RoutePostAccount(object):

    @staticmethod
    def on_get(req, resp):

        # Convert query parameters string to dict
        _payload = uri.parse_query_string(req.query_string)
        # Create account
        _result = account.create_account(**_payload)
        # Send response
        resp.status = _result.get('status', {}).get('code')
        resp.body = json.dumps(_result)
```

Comment: That was it! `json.dumps(_result)` solved it. Thank you very much!